# How to automate installing new jar project on my ssh server?

Tags: java, ssh, jar, ftp

I started working on my first Rest API project in spring boot. I created some less advanced program that works. The project have plugin which helps me with creating new .jar file which can be installed on my VPS server by SSH client. At the bottom I present the diagram that must be taken to install correctly the .jar file on serwer.

1. After testing everything and getting the correct result I have to clear existing .jar in project by typing "mvn clean".
2. Later I must create new modyfied .jar package by command "mvn package"
3. Moving file from my local files to remote files in VPS server for example in WinSCP/FileZilla FTP client.
4. After it must login in SSH clinent and install it by "java -jar "api.jar"

As u can see it takes a lot of time. Exist any programs or something which can I programming to makes it automatically ? I heard something about Jenkins ? 
Do you have any advice that would save me some time :D?

Many thanks and sorry for my english, I know it is not good enought but I did my best :D
Simone

Comment: you can try maven wagon plugin https://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/usage.html . As i know it can help you to transfer jar and run custom commands, like `java -jar`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What do you mean by "it takes a lot of time", and why is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be achieved using jenkins.
First commit your code to git repository.
Once you have jenkins installed on your system. 
From jenkins dashboard select new item. 
Enter name of this item
Then select the type, you should select 'Pipeline'.
In next page select advance project options in definition section follow the sample code shared below to create your own pipeline script.

For more information on pipeline visit [Jenkins pipeline getting started](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/)

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
```

node('master') {

```
        try {
        def mvnHome
        def projectDirectoryPath
        def serverPath = '/app/projects/myapp/services/'
        def jarName = 'myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'

        stage('checkout') {
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/YOURGITBRANCH']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'YOURGITCREDENTIALID', url: 'YOURGITURL']]])
            mvnHome = '/usr/apache-maven-3.1.1'
            projectDirectoryPath = '/app/jenkins-slave/workspace/myapp_services'
        }

        stage('clean') {
            sh "cd '${projectDirectoryPath}' && '${mvnHome}/bin/mvn' clean"
        }

        stage('build') {
            sh "cd '${projectDirectoryPath}' && '${mvnHome}/bin/mvn' package"
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/target/*.jar', fingerprint: true
        }

        stage('deploy') {
            sshagent(['YOURAGENTID']) {
                   echo "the application is deploying ${jarName}"
                   sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USER@YOURHOST ${serverPath}stop.sh"
                   echo "the ${jarName} is stopped"
                   sh "scp ${projectDirectoryPath}/target/${jarName}  USER@YOURHOST:${serverPath}${jarName}"
                   echo "the ${jarName} is transferred successfuly"
                   sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USER@YOURHOST sh ${serverPath}start_silent.sh"
                   echo "the ${jarName} is started successfuly"
            }
        }

    }catch(e){
       currentBuild.result="FAILED"
       //notifyfailed()
     throw e 
}
```

}